# how to retrieve data from multiple table using one mysql query

Tags: mysql, join, virtuemart

I try to write a query in order to retrieve full info for our product in virtuemart 2.

First I try with single INNER JOIN like the example bellow:

```
    $query ="select p.`virtuemart_product_id`, p.`product_name`, p.`product_s_desc`, `pmqbw_virtuemart_product_categories`.`virtuemart_category_id`

    FROM `pmqbw_virtuemart_products_el_gr` AS p 
    INNER JOIN `pmqbw_virtuemart_product_categories` ON p.`virtuemart_product_id`=`pmqbw_virtuemart_product_categories`.`virtuemart_product_id`
    LIMIT 0 ,10";
```

The above worked well!

Then I tried to be more complex and I wrote the following:

```
    $query ="select p.`virtuemart_product_id`, p.`product_name`, p.`product_s_desc`,    `pmqbw_virtuemart_product_categories`.`virtuemart_category_id`, `pmqbw_virtuemart_categories_el_gr`.`category_name`

    FROM `pmqbw_virtuemart_products_el_gr` AS p

    INNER JOIN p 
ON `pmqbw_virtuemart_product_categories`.`virtuemart_product_id`=p.`virtuemart_product_id`


    INNER JOIN `pmqbw_virtuemart_categories_el_gr` AS x
ON x.`virtuemart_category_id`=`pmqbw_virtuemart_product_categories`.`virtuemart_category_id`

LIMIT 0 ,10";
```

But something goes wrong here and I cannot understand.

After that I'll try to retrieve more tables and more joins in order to bring product data I need.

Thank you for your help in advance!

---

Actually I want to retrieve data from the following tables.
From `pmqbw_virtuemart_products_el_gr I want fields: product_name, product_s_desc,`virtuemart_product_id`

From `pmqbw_virtuemart_product_categories` I want fields: virtuemart_product_id,    virtuemart_category_id

From `pmqbw_virtuemart_categories_el_gr` I want fields: virtuemart_category_id, category_name

From `pmqbw_virtuemart_product_medias` I want fields: virtuemart_product_id,    virtuemart_media_id

`pmqbw_virtuemart_medias` I want fields:  virtuemart_media_id, file_url, file_url_thumb     where file_mimetype=image/jpeg AND file_type=product

I tried a different query with left joins but does not work as well.

```
    $sql = "SELECT N.product_name,I.virtuemart_media_id,M.virtuemart_product_id,MN.category_name 

FROM pmqbw_virtuemart_categories_el_gr AS M 

LEFT JOIN pmqbw_virtuemart_products AS P ON P.virtuemart_product_id = M.virtuemart_product_id

LEFT JOIN pmqbw_virtuemart_products_el_gr  AS N ON N.virtuemart_product_id = M.virtuemart_product_id

LEFT JOIN pmqbw_virtuemart_product_medias  AS I ON I.virtuemart_product_id = M.virtuemart_product_id

LEFT JOIN pmqbw_virtuemart_product_categories AS MN ON MN.virtuemart_category_id = M.virtuemart_category_id

WHERE M.virtuemart_category_id = 1";
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Thank you all for the help!

the query that runs ok is the following:

```
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT X.virtuemart_product_id, X.product_name, M.category_name, Y.virtuemart_product_id, W.file_url

    FROM pmqbw_virtuemart_products_el_gr AS X
    INNER JOIN pmqbw_virtuemart_product_categories AS P ON P.virtuemart_product_id = X.virtuemart_product_id
    AND P.virtuemart_category_id =2

    INNER JOIN pmqbw_virtuemart_categories_el_gr AS M ON M.virtuemart_category_id = P.virtuemart_category_id"

    INNER JOIN pmqbw_virtuemart_product_medias AS Y ON Y.virtuemart_product_id = X.virtuemart_product_id

    INNER JOIN pmqbw_virtuemart_medias AS W ON W.virtuemart_media_id = Y.virtuemart_media_id;
```

The bud thing is that every product has two or more images and I only want one.
I have to think something in order to eliminate it!
If anyone has something in his mind for help will be more than welcome!

Thank you!

Ok, I find a solution with GROUP BY Y.virtuemart_product_id
:)

Thank you all !

Comment: What are you trying to do with `INNER JOIN p` ?

Comment: Actually I try to retrieve a list of products which data are in 6 different tables.

Comment: Incidentally, LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless

Comment: You're using aliases that don't exist AND not using aliases that DO!?! (although your final example is fine)

Comment: @Spyros - I think Filipe Silva meant that `INNER JOIN p` does not seem to fit. You would use `INNER JOIN   pmqbw_virtuemart_product_categoriesas t ON t.virtuemart_product_id = p.virtuemart_product_id`